is this normal lens flare or is something wrong with the lens
I have a rf 35mm 1.8 lens on the r10. noticed some evident lens flares during night photography. the flare shape is kind of weird there's like an eye at the center.
Is this normal or is there something wrong with my lens? any insight greatly appreciated.
I have no lens hood when shots were taken and im usually at f2 1/16




This question is similar to: is it normal to get significant lens flare with a 50mm f/1.8 prime lens?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Different lens, exact same problem and explanation as the suggested duplicate above. Please also see: Does high reflectiveness of digital sensor lead to poor lens performance? and What could cause this visible artifact which seems to a be a glowing inverse of something outside of the frame overlayed on this photograph?

Do you also have a flat UV or "protective" filter attached to the front of your lens?

yeah its somehow similar with the 50mm post. but i think mine shows something at the center of the post. like a little eye.

also this is an rf lens, i'm thinking the lens should have improve than an ef one. just asking if someone also has an rf lens that behaves the same way

i have a cpl. i tried removing it when i first notice but flares still persist

"also this is an rf lens, i'm thinking the lens should have improve than an ef one" Why?

@PhilipKendall Early EF lenses were designed in the film era. Film is much less reflective than the filter stack in front of digital sensors. Lenses designed after the popularization of digital photography often have anti-reflective coatings on the back of some lens elements to combat this. But if specular highlights are bright enough and the surrounding parts of the scene are dark enough, even the best lenses can still ghost under such conditions..

@fancyfootball Your example images are classic examples of ghosting. Strong specular highlights in an otherwise dark scene show up as reversed and inverted "ghosts" due to reflections bouncing around in the lens and possibly involving the filter stack in front of the camera's sensor and any flat filters attached to the lens. Perfectly flat surfaces are the most likely to cause ghosting, but they're not the only ones.

@fancyfootball The cats eye bokeh is common on wide aperture lenses because sometimes the edge of the lens' front element is not visible all the way around the rim of the lens due to the end of the lens barrel partially blocking light from the widest parts of the lens.

To my eye, those look like internal reflections of light sources in frame.
This is an unavoidable consequence of mult-element lenses and bright light sources; at every air-glass, glass-air, or glass-glass transition, there will be a low percentage of light reflected rather than transmitted (1% or less with a modern lens coating), which can then rereflect from another interface to find its way back to the sensor/film and be detected.  The low percentage prevents large overall contrast loss (which was the original reason to start coating lenses and the discovery of coating effects), but can't completely eliminate recorded reflections of light sources much brighter than the overall correctly exposed frame.
In your case, there's a significant halo around each reflection, and only a single visible reflection of each source, suggesting (as one comment on the question asked) that you have a filter mounted and that the filter is either poorly coated or has a surface haze.  Your question says you don't have a filter mounted for these frames, but many camera sensors have a built-in infrared-blocking filter layer (required due to the high IR sensitivity of most silicon digital sensors) and surface contamination of that filter layer could produce the halo effect from reflections inside a clean lens.  Otherwise, these halos may indicate a film (lubricant from aperture blades or zoom mechanism, perhaps) on the internal lens surface that's producing these primary reflections.
